# resize table column using jquery

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/  if i expand and shrink the column  I want the items to stay on the same line is it possible ?

```
<h1><a href="http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable">Resize columns and tables </a></h1>
<p> With colResizable you can resize and drag columns in html tables</p>
<table id="sample" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20%;">header</th><th style="width: 40%;">header</th>                            <th style="width: 15%;">header</th><th style="width: 25%;">header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td>
    </tr>               
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<p> Using colResizable it is also posible to customize the column anchors and make them look as you want</p>
<table id="sample2" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th style="width: 20%;">header</th><th style="width: 40%;">header</th><th style="width: 15%;">header</th><th style="width: 25%;">header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td>
</tr>               
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<p>it also can handle non-fixed tables so you can resize columns independetly</p>
<table id="nonFixedSample"  width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td>
    </tr>                                                                   
    </table>
```

**js**

```
$("#sample").colResizable({liveDrag:true});

$("#sample2").colResizable({
    liveDrag:true,
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging" });


$("#nonFixedSample").colResizable({
    fixed:false,
    liveDrag:true,
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip2'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging" 
});
```

**css**

```
body{

   background:none;
    background-color:white;
}

p{
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:6px;

}
```

Comment: it already stays in same line... can you plz explain your problem little better?

Comment: if i write table data i am rakib instead cell then shrink then the entire line is not in the same line go to next line one by one

Comment: @RakibAhmed: but the fiddle which you have attached doesnt show the problem.. please create the problem in the fiddle and share.

Comment: add `td  {
  white-space:nowrap;
}` kincly check http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/1118/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/1119/ here u see when i shrink cell is beauty is not in the same line what should i do to make it inline?

Comment: its working thanks